# Check available software update available for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, version

In my project I want to check whether my iPhone's (system's) iOS version is updated to latest released apple iOS version or not..

For getting current iPhone iOS version I have used following code

```
var systemVersion = UIDevice.current.systemVersion
```

I would like to know is there any way by which I came to know the latest iOS released by apple??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no public API available to check the latest iOS Version *available* at the moment.

What you can do is probably set-up an API at your own server and use it to check the latest iOS version available. Of Course that means manually updating the API whenever a new version is released by apple.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it by latest version check by this code

`let floatVersion = (UIDevice.current.systemVersion as NSString).floatValue`

Comment: Its giving current operating version.. but I want latest iOS version released by apple which we generally get in software update(Setting-General-Software Update)